# PHP : page loading for infinite time

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am scraping products from a website using simple html dom parser and i have written the following code for this

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once('lib/simple_html_dom.php');
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    ini_set('max_input_time ', '99999');
    $url='http://www.yourpoolhq.com/pool-supplies/aboveground/pool-liners/round/unibead.html';
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    if(is_object($html)){
        foreach ( $html->find('div.category-products') as $elem ){

            $data = $elem->innertext;
            $strdata = str_get_html($data);
            foreach ($strdata->find('a') as $a) {
                    if($a->plaintext!=''){
                        get_detail_page($a->href);
                        flush();

                    }
                    flush();
            }
            unset($data);
            unset($strdata);
        }
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);
    }

    function get_detail_page($href){
    $details = file_get_html($href);
        if(is_object($details)){

            foreach ($details->find('h1') as $ess ) {
                                //print_r($ess); this has data 
                echo $ess->plaintext; // not getting this, Why this is not printing. x-(                                                            
                flush();    
            }
            $details->clear();
            unset($details);
        }
    flush();    
}


    ?>
```

Not getting what wrong i am doing here. Any idea guys.

Edit: I have updated the code added flush at some places and comment the error section.

Comment: Clear one junk of code and see if that works. and add everytime one piece of code to see what cause the problem

Comment: show us your file_get_html()?

Comment: the code is not working under the get_detail_page() page after the file_get_html() is not working... :'(

Comment: Its the function of simple_html_dom.php http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself does not have any glaring flaws. The only thing I can think of is `file_get_html` taking an awfully long time due to latency between your server and the remote server at somedomain.com. It might be worth investigating via latency tools (tracert, ping etc on the server that you are using PHP on).

Comment: You could be right but when i try directly calling get_detail_page($url) this is working normally but when i place this in loop with upper code it start irritating me mozilla saying :  The connection was reset

Comment: @ravisoni: Okay. So, if it is working when you manually provide the $url, I guess it is either a. timing out mid-request, or b. the URL it receives is malformed. Could you investigate both, please? (Also, to the coward who downvotes without leaving the reason why - always appreciated)

Comment: check the code now its nearly done but the text is not getting :'(

Comment: I don't care about the downvote rep change itself - I would like to know *why* I was downvoted. The best way to learn and improve is to know the mistakes I've made. As for the bug, can you try checking the content of outertext?